# Error "No matching function for call to..." al usar constructor en clase derivada

Tags: c++, poo, herencia

Tengo un programa que debe calcular las operaciones matemáticas básicas (suma, resta, multiplicación
y división) a través de objetos que heredan de una clase común. La clase Elementales contiene el
método virtual proceso() y las clases Suma, Resta, Mult y Div deben heredar de esta y sobreescribir
dicho método para que realice la operación que indica su nombre e imprima el resultado.

El problema viene cuanto intento construir los objetos, los cuales tienen un constructor sin argumentos y no hacen nada pero aún así el compilador me da un mensaje enorme enmedio del cual se distingue el error:

> No matching function for call to Elementales::Elementales()

que aparece por cada una de las clases de mi proyecto.

Dejo a su disposición todo el mensaje de compilación y el código correspondiente.

> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp||In constructor 'Suma::Suma()':|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|14|error: no matching function for call to 'Elementales::Elementales()'|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note: candidate: Elementales::Elementales(float&, float&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(const Elementales&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(Elementales&&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp||In constructor 'Resta::Resta()':|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|19|error: no matching function for call to 'Elementales::Elementales()'|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note: candidate: Elementales::Elementales(float&, float&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(const Elementales&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(Elementales&&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp||In constructor 'Mult::Mult()':|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|24|error: no matching function for call to 'Elementales::Elementales()'|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note: candidate: Elementales::Elementales(float&, float&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(const Elementales&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(Elementales&&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp||In constructor 'Div::Div()':|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|29|error: no matching function for call to 'Elementales::Elementales()'|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note: candidate: Elementales::Elementales(float&, float&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(const Elementales&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note: candidate: constexpr Elementales::Elementales(Elementales&&)|
>   C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Exa1.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>   ||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Mi codigo es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Elementales{
public:
    Elementales(float &,float &);
virtual void proceso();
protected:
float a,b,c;};
class Suma:public Elementales{
public:
Suma(){};
   virtual void proceso();
};
class Resta:public Elementales{
public:
    Resta(){};
   virtual void proceso();
};
class Mult:public Elementales{
public:
    Mult(){};
   void proceso();
};
class Div:public Elementales{
public:
    Div(){};
void proceso();
};
Elementales::Elementales(float &a1,float &b1){
a=a1;
b=b1;
}
void Elementales::proceso(){
c=a+b;
cout<<"El resultado del residuo es: "<<c;
}
void Suma::proceso(){
c=a+b;
cout<<"El resultado de la suma es "<<c;
}
void Resta::proceso(){
c=a-b;
cout<<"El resultado de la resta es "<<c;
}
void Mult::proceso(){
c=a*b;
cout<<"El resultado de la multiplicacion es "<<c;
}
void Div::proceso(){
c=a/b;
cout<<"El resultado de la division es "<<c;
}
int main(){
int x;
system("CLS");
do{
    float a1,b1;
    cout<<"Dame el primer numero "<<endl;
    cin>>a1;
    cout<<"Dame el segundo numero "<<endl;
    cin>>b1;
    Elementales ob(a1,b1);
    Suma ob2;
    Resta ob3;
    Mult ob4;
    Div ob5;
    ob.proceso();
    Elementales *p=&ob2;
    p -> proceso();
    p = &ob3;
    p -> proceso();
    p = &ob4;
    p -> proceso();
    p = &ob5;
    p -> proceso();
    system("Pause");
    cout<<"Quieres volver a hacer una operacion?"<<"1.Si"<<endl<<"2.No"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
}while(x==1);
}
```

Alguien me podria ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error bastante interesante entre manos que requiere tener en cuenta unos conceptos clave.

Primero: El constructor de una clase derivada (Aquella que hereda de otra) siempre llama a uno de los constructores de su clase base de forma implícita o explícita.
Cuando no llamas ningún constructor del padre de forma explícita, el compilador intentará hacer por defecto una llamada al constructor sin argumentos.

Segundo: Cuando una clase no define ningún constructor, el compilador agrega un constructor por defecto que no tiene argumentos. Este constructor por defecto ya no es añadido siempre que definamos uno o más constructores para nuestra clase.

En tu caso, la clase base "Elementales" define un constructor de dos argumentos:

```
Elementales(float &, float &);
```

De acuerdo al segundo concepto anotado antes, como tu clase define un constructor, el compilador no añadirá el constructor por defecto, lo cual significa que si intentamos construir un "Elementales" de la siguiente manera: Elementales e();
Habría un error de compilación.

Sin embargo el problema no es con el constructor de Elementales, sino con los de sus clases derivadas: Suma, Resta, Mula y Div. Cada una de las clases mencionadas define su propio constructor sin argumentos y con el cuerpo vacío tal como sigue:

```
Suma(){}
Resta(){}
Mult(){}
Div(){}
```

Aunque a simple vista ninguno de esos constructores hacen nada, el primer concepto importante nos recuerda que en realidad cada uno está intentando llamar al constructor sin argumentos de la clase base por lo que en realidad el código se vería así:

```
Suma() : Elementales() {}
Resta() : Elementales() {}
Mult() : Elementales() {}
Div() : Elementales() {}
```

Como la clase padre no define un constructor sin argumentos y el compilador no añade uno por defecto por la razones ya vistas, las líneas anteriores producirán el error que marca tu código: No matching function for call to Elementales::Elementales() {}

Simplemente habíamos intentado llamar a un constructor que no existía sin darnos cuenta porque al principio esa llamada estaba oculta. La forma de solucionarlo es hacer que cada constructor de las clases derivadas reciba también los objetos que necesita la clase base y se los pase en una llamada explícita al constructor de dos argumentos:

```
Suma(float & a, float & b) : Elementales(a, b) {}
Resta(float & a, float & b) : Elementales(a, b) {}
Mult(float & a, float & b) : Elementales(a, b) {}
Div(float & a, float & b) : Elementales(a, b) {}
```

Y entonces la construcción de los objetos tendría que ir a la par:

```
Suma ob2(a1, b1);
Resta ob3(a1, b1);
Mult ob3(a1, b1);
Div ob4(a1, b1);
```

** Nota: Si solamente te interesaba solucionar tu código puedes dejar de leer en este punto. Si quieres algunas notas extra sobre como mejorar tu código puedes seguir leyendo. Algunas de las características del lenguaje que se van a mostrar son recientes y no están habilitadas por defecto en algunos compiladores por lo que podrían requerir que busques información sobre como habilitarlas en el IDE/compilador con que trabajes. **

A ya que estamos, es probable que tengas algún error de concepto sobre lo que es la herencia por la forma justamente por la forma en que construías tus objetos anteriormente:

```
Elementales ob(a1, b1);

Suma ob2;
Resta ob3;
Mult ob4;
Div ob5;
```

Aunque habías inicializado correctamente ob, el hecho de que creyeras que estaba bien simplemente construir el resto de objetos sin argumentos indica que pensabas que había una relación entre ellos y que al haber dicho a ob los ob los datos de trabajo todos los demás los conocerían mágicamente después. Es cierto que las clases tienen cierta relación, sin embargo cada objeto creado a partir de ellas tiene datos independientes entre sí y con su propio espacio en memoria. Eso significa que aunque C++ funcionara diferente y tu código hubiera compilado, seguiría estando erróneo porque solamente ob tendría datos correctos mientras que todos los demás simplemente tendrían basura.

El verdadero objetivo de la herencia no es que los datos se compartan sino que los objetos compartan características similares y que se puedan procesar polimorficamente, cosa que tu programa no hace.  Una forma de ver realmente los beneficios de la herencia sustituir el uso de un solo apuntador por por un contenedor que guardara todos los objetos y que luego los procesara en un ciclo de la siguiente forma:

```
vector<Elementales *> operaciones { &ob2, &ob3, &ob4, &ob5 };

for (Elementales * p : operaciones)
    p->proceso();
```

Por otro lado, el uso de referencias en tu constructor de Elementales no hace mucho sentido en ese contexto pues a fin de cuentas internamente se termina haciendo una copia de los valores igualmente.  Si lo hacías solamente para que tu código fuera más rápido deberías saber que el compilador es muy bueno por si solo para optimizar ese tipo de cosas por lo que es justificación suficiente pues externamente quienes hagan uso de esta clase pueden confundirse y pensar erróneamente que las variables que envían van a ser modificadas. Lo recomendable es simplemente recibir variables normales en lugar de referencias siempre que no sea necesario. Solamente si el rendimiento es crítico y la construcción de copia es potencialmente costosa (y es tal que es difícil que sea optimizada por el compilador) se debería usar referencias como argumentos aunque no se vayan a modificar y aún con esas se debería marcar cada argumento con el modificador "const" para que quienes hagan uso de el sepan que sus datos no serán modificados.

Otra práctica cuestionable en tu código es el uso del tipo "float" en lugar de "double". Lo cierto es que rara vez ha habido una buena razón para preferir números de punto flotante de precisión simple sobre los de precisión double. Generalmente tanto la ganancia en tiempo de ejecución como en espacio son imperceptibles o simplemente inexistentes y la precisión de los cálculos baja considerablemente. Los tipos "float" desde un inicio solo estaban pensados para cuando la eficiencia era vital y se tenían que manejar grandes cantidades de datos que no cabían por completo en la memoria caché. Para solo un par de variables la elección por defecto debería ser usar un double.

Siempre deberías pensar dos veces antes de usar "using namespace std" pues estás poblando el espacio
de nombres global innecesariamente y el llamar a la función "system()" nuestro código es dependiente
del ambiente de ejecución en lugar de simplemente usar características estándar del lenguaje.
Cuando una clase derivada sobrescribe un método de la clase base debería marcar dicho método con
override para ser específicos.

Tomando todo eso en cuenta, el código quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

class Elemental
{
  public:
    Elemental(double, double);
    virtual void proceso();

  protected:
    double a, b;
};

class Suma : public Elemental
{
  public:
    Suma(double a, double b) : Elemental(a, b) {}
    virtual void proceso() override;
};
class Resta : public Elemental
{
  public:
    Resta(double a, double b) : Elemental(a, b){}
    virtual void proceso() override;
};
class Mult : public Elemental
{
  public:
    Mult(double a, double b) : Elemental(a, b){}
    void proceso() override;
};
class Div : public Elemental
{
  public:
    Div(double a, double b) : Elemental(a, b){}
    void proceso() override;
};

Elemental::Elemental(double a, double b)
{
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
}
void Elemental::proceso()
{
    std::cout << "El resultado del residuo es: " << a + b << std::endl;
}
void Suma::proceso()
{
    std::cout << "El resultado de la suma es " << a + b << std::endl;
}
void Resta::proceso()
{
    std::cout << "El resultado de la resta es " << a - b << std::endl;
}
void Mult::proceso()
{
    std::cout << "El resultado de la multiplicación es " << a * b << std::endl;
}
void Div::proceso()
{
    std::cout << "El resultado de la división es " <<  a / b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int opcion;

    do {
        double a, b;
        std::cout << "Dame el primer número " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << "Dame el segundo número " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> b;

        Elemental ob{a, b};

        Suma  ob2{a, b};
        Resta ob3{a, b};
        Mult  ob4{a, b};
        Div   ob5{a, b};

        // Se guarda una copia de cada ob en un vector para llamarlos
        // en conjunto. Según que casos podría ser ineficiente e indeseable.
        // En esos caso usar un vector de punteros a Elemental para
        // guardar solamente las direcciones
        std::vector<Elemental *> operaciones { &ob2, &ob3, &ob4, &ob5 };

        for (auto op : operaciones)
        {
            op->proceso();
        }

        std::cout << "Presione enter para continuar . . ." << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

        std::cout << "¿Quieres volver a hacer una operación?" << std::endl
                  << "1.Si" << std::endl
                  << "2.No" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> opcion;
    } while (opcion == 1);
}
```

Comment: Su respuesta está muy bien. Sólo una observación: ha duplicado los párrafos de su respuesta justo después de "el código quedaría así:"

Comment: Corregido, gracias @Xam